# Store image with redis - cli?

Tags: redis

i'm new to redis and learning how to use it. I have and exercise require create a shopping cart redis db using client id as key and store image using commands. I've research on redis commands site and others but only find ways to do the task using python or nodejs. Can any one show me some example doing it with commands?. Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat spam_comments.png | redis-cli  -x  set spam_comments.png

redis-cli get spam_comments.png > /tmp/img.png

 $ redis-cli get spam_comments.png > /tmp/img.png
 $ file img.png 
   img.png: PNG image data, 392 x 66, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
```